# How to prevent decoding of bytes from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, adafruit-circuitpython

I am reading a bmp file 4 bytes at a time to gather colors from a .bmp file to create a palette. When I read the file, I get `b'\x8b\xc3\**x00J**\x00'`. If I open this file in a hex editor, the string of bytes is `b'\x8b\xc3\**x4a**\x00`. Now that specific byte breaks the program when I try to put it in a `dispalyio.palette`. My understanding is that Python auto decodes bytes (that have a valid ascii representation) to ascii.

Ultimately I want to just get the raw string of bytes, 4 bytes at a time, without the decoding from said file. My code looks like this:

```
palette = displayio.Palette(2)
with open("images/f.bmp", "rb") as f:
    f.seek(137)
    for val in range(0, 1):
        try:
            c_bytes = f.read(4)
            #print(c_bytes[0:2])
            print(b''.join([c_bytes[3:4], c_bytes[2:3], c_bytes[0:2]]))
            palette[0] = b''.join([c_bytes[3:4], c_bytes[1:3], c_bytes[0:2]])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

This is on CircuitPython 6.3.0 using the `displayio` module. For those unfamiliar CircuitPython is just a slimmed down version of python for MCU, and it uses Python 3 as a base.

Comment: That "auto decoding" is something that only happens when computing a `repr` of the bytes for display; the actual bytestring contains exactly the bytes you want. In fact, there's no possible way a bytestring could contain decoded characters "instead of" raw bytes; a bytestring *can only hold* bytes.

Comment: Also, why are you slicing past the end of `c_bytes`? You read 4 bytes with `f.read(4)`, but then you try to take a slice `c_bytes[4:6]`.

Comment: I was just about to mention that! It is a remnant from past slicing that I forgot to remove. If I try to slice the x00J portion of the byte string, I have to slice from [0:2] whereas if I had x4a, I only had to slice from  [0:1]. When I go to read a seperate file, this breaks it because it reads too far so it seems like something is going on with the way the x00j is getting stored or I'm misunderstanding your comment

Comment: `b'\x8b\xc3\x00J\x00'` would be 5 bytes. You only read 4. There's no way that `f.read()` call returned `b'\x8b\xc3\x00J\x00'`. What does `print(c_bytes)` show?

Comment: And why are you putting `c_bytes[3:4]` into the palette twice?

Comment: that prints `b'\x00J\xc3\x8b` which would be 4 bytes right? And the slice returns `b'\x8b\xc3\x00J'` which flips the first and last byte which is what my intention is. The 5 bytes was the issue with setting it equal to palette, but that still presents me the same issue where if I open another file and try to do the same thing, it slices to far with the 0:2 and gets me three chars instead of 2. Also, putting that in twice was unintentional when I just C&Ped it. Removed it, thank you for being patient!

Comment: Your code doesn’t make a lot of sense.    `c_bytes = f.read(4)` is all you need. Casting to bytes is unnecessary it is already bytes. Make a [mcve] what is the point of all the slicing? And the `for` only runs one loop so why is it there?

Comment: The slicing is to flip the first and last byte which would be the RGB in the values. It is read in as BGR so I have to reverse it.

Comment: You have two different flippings, and I'm not sure either is correct. `x = b''.join([c_bytes[3:], c_bytes[1:2], c_bytes[:1]]); print(x); palette[0] = x`.

Comment: You might just want to make three separate reads to simplify it: `b, g, r = f.read(1), f.read(2), f.read(1); x = b''.join([r, g, b])`.

Comment: Or `b, g, r = struct.unpack('ss2s', f.read(4))`.

Comment: From a string of `b'\x00J\xc3\x8b'`, your modified slice gives me a final string of `b'\x8bJ\x00'` when what I need it to be is `b'\x8b\xc3\x00J'` Let me give those following suggestions a go though! @chepner

Comment: OK, you want `c_bytes[3:], c_bytes[2:3], c_bytes[:2]`, as in your `print` statement. It's the one in your assignment to `palette` that's wrong. But there's no reason to make the split twice (and risk errors like these).

Comment: @chepner If I use the provided slice, when I try to pull green (which is the `b'\x00J\xc3\x8b'`) it works great, but if I try to pull white, which comes in as `b'\x00\xff\xff\xff'` then it actually has 4 bytes and gets messed up due to the fact that I have to slice it in accordance to the first string that has only 3 bytes there vs the second string which has 4 bytes. This is the ultimate problem here.

Comment: `b'\x00J\xc3\x8b'` has 4 bytes: `\x00`, `J`, `\xc3`, and `\x8b`. Don't get hung up on the fact that `bytes.__repr__` displays a byte as a printable ASCII character when it can, resorting to `\x...` only when it has to. `b'J'` and `b'\x4a'` are the exact same value.

Comment: Okay that definitely makes sense more sense then. Thank you so much for the clarification. I was extremely thrown off by the way the J was getting printed. I adjusted the slice to `[c_bytes[3:], c_bytes[2:3], c_bytes[1:2]]` and it works perfectly now. I thought the `x00J` was necessary but it appears the string is perfectly fine as `b'\x8b\xc3J'`. Thank you!